# Using signalr_client package in flutter application, setting authorization header. FormatException: Invalid HTTP header field name

Tags: .net, flutter, signalr, webapi

I'm trying to connect my flutter app to a hub in my .net core application.

this is what I'm trying :

```
// Connection to the signalr Hub
  _connectToHub() async {
    // The location of the SignalR Server.
    final serverUrl = "https://192.168.1.65:5001/notification";
    // Creates the connection by using the HubConnectionBuilder.
    final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(serverUrl,
            options: new HttpConnectionOptions(accessTokenFactory: () async {return await FlutterSession().get("token");}))
        .build();
    await hubConnection.start().then((value){print("CONNECTED TO HOST HUB");}).onError((error, stackTrace){
      print(stackTrace);
      print(error);
    });
    hubConnection.on("simo", _invokedSimo);
    // When the connection is closed, print out a message to the console.
    hubConnection.onclose( (error) => print("Connection Closed"));
  }
```

this is the stack trace :

> I/flutter (15069): #0      HttpConnection._startInternal
> (package:signalr_client/http_connection.dart:255:7) I/flutter (15069):
>  I/flutter (15069): #1
> HubConnection.start (package:signalr_client/hub_connection.dart:103:5)
> I/flutter (15069):  I/flutter (15069): #2
> FutureExtensions.onError. (dart:async/future.dart)
> I/flutter (15069):  I/flutter (15069):
> FormatException: Invalid HTTP header field name: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJ..

After a little bit of research this is where the code of the package breaks :

```
final response = await _httpClient.post(negotiateUrl, options: options);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I had to modify one line in the package itself :

in the file http_connection.dart : method : *_getNegotiationResponse*

```
if (_accessTokenFactory != null) {
      final token = await _accessTokenFactory();
      if (token != null) {
        headers.setHeaderValue("Authorization", "$token");
      }
    }
```

instead of "Bearer $token" ....
I guess because this function doesn't support strings with space character.